# Prefill a Google Form link using data from spreadsheet with text masking

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I've been struggling with this for a few weeks and have gone as far as I can with my limited knowledge of formulas (and my totally absent knowledge of scripts).

1. I'm trying to create a prefilled link to a Google Form filled with data contained in a Google Sheet (done).
2. The prefilled link should be easy to replicate over thousands of rows by simply dragging the hyperlink formula, making it unique to the data contained in each row (done).
3. The prefilled link should be masked in the sheet by text, the way any other hyperlink is masked by text (not done).

Steps 1 and 2 work like the example below and populate the form quite nicely:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform?entry.1079682270&entry.13269831&entry.106264669=="&A2&E2)
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform?entry.1079682270&entry.13269831&entry.106264669=="&A3&E3)
```

But I would like it to also be masked by text as is done in a typical hyperlink formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform","Reserve Now")
```

If anyone can help, I'd be eternally grateful!  For reference, here is a link to the Drive folder showing the actual Sheet and Form I'm working with:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ww3yce65L2MUs0WVNBOW5LRnM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add one more parameter like this:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform?entry.1079682270&entry.13269831&entry.106264669=="&A2&E2,"Reserve Now")
```

That will add your text.

You can also do an arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform?entry.1079682270&entry.13269831&entry.106264669=="&A2:A&E2:E,"Reserve Now"),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assume that A1 constains

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf7_ZUEXce6RTvHxzsIIMnUrOj2bcdIh9WSGG1V_0LHlM8QDg/viewform?entry.1079682270&entry.13269831&entry.106264669==
```

Then try something like the following:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1&A2&E2,"Reserve Now")
```